# C++ : Creating program that reads a text file

Tags: c++

I need help I am new. My text below has been created on a separate file(`football.txt`). I am trying to create a program that can read that data and have it displayed.

```
Player name:    Rusell William
Salaray:        $8000000
Age:            20
Team:           Seahawks
Position:       Quarterback
```

This is what i have,

```
//This program will read the text files into display

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

//Declaring Variables

    int salary, age;
    string firstName, lastName, team, position;

//Delcaring a file.

    ifstream infile;
    infile.open("football.txt", ios::in);

    if (!infile)
{   cout<<"File does not exist";
}

    infile.close();

    ofstream outfile;

//Declare on display

    cout<<"**********Player Summary*********\n";
    outfile.open("football.txt", ios::app);
    outfile<<"football.txt";
    outfile.close();




return 0;
}
```

No Errors, however no displayed neither.

Comment: Use a debugger or learn from the examples of others by searching the internet for "stackoverflow c++ read file space separated".

Comment: Read more on C++ I/O. C++ I/O is not as abstract as you think (i.e., one command and you're done).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this sample program and build up on it:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
    ifstream infile;
    infile.open("football.txt", ios::in);

    if (!infile)
    {
       cout<<"File does not exist";
       return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    std::string text_from file;
    while (getline(infile, text_from_file))
    {
       cout << text_from_file << "\n";
    }

    cout << "Paused. Press enter to continue.\n"
    cin.ignore(10000, '\n');

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Notice that text is being read from the file using the `getline` function.

Comment: Looks very helpful, but, we haven't learned "while" yet. I'll see what i can do with the few comments that helped, thank you.

Comment: It worked out great!! Thank you everyone for your little bits n pieces of help :D